# Installation error:autobahn 18.5.1 has requirement six>=1.10.0, but you'll have six 1.5.2 which is incompatible

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, ibm-watson

I'm trying to install watson_developer_cloud for my python 2.7 in Ubuntu 14. I used following command

```
sudo pip install --upgrade watson-developer-cloud
```

And got following error message

```
autobahn 18.5.1 has requirement six>=1.10.0, but you'll have six 1.5.2 which is incompatible.
Cannot uninstall 'pyOpenSSL'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Can you suggest me how to resolve this issue?